# how to operate with values from dictionary in a condtional statement in a django template

Tags: django, dictionary, if-statement, django-templates

in my django template I have a conditional statement which involves value from a dictionary

```
{%if {{y}} > 1 %}
        color: '#4d0099'
        {% endif %}
```

where y is a numeric value.i want to apply this if statement on it but i am getting an error of

> Could not parse the remainder: '{{y}}' from '{{y}}'

Comment: Use `{% if y > 1 %}`. Variables are not wrapped in curly brackets in a template tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a template tag you use variables without curly brackets, so:

```
{% if y > 1 %}
    color: '#4d0099'
{% endif %}
```